# What to do when the KLM site mentions you can not check in online for a KLM flight

Tags: check-in, ams, klm, brs

I booked a flight on the KLM site several months in advance and got the line: "U kunt niet online inchecken voor deze vlucht."
(You can't check in online for this flight.)
The flight is on a national holiday and I was pretty much sure at the time that the reason for not being able to check in online was that holiday.
This is a standard flight, booked on the KLM site directly, by someone who is a Dutch citizen and who has checked in online with KLM several times in the last few years.

Is there an other option and still be able to check in more than three hours before the flight?

Comment: Which airport are you leaving from? Some airports do not allow online check-in.

Comment: In this case it was between two airports I had used before, always being able to check in online.

Comment: This year I used the app, that tells you how many hours till check-in opens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is very easy, thirty hours before the flight, in this case, the line disappeared and was replaced by the invitation to check in now.

So it was not about it being on a national holiday, it was just the flight not yet being open to be checked in.

Of course, not all KLM flights open for checking in 30 hours before departure, in the case it is a different length of time before checking in is allowed, the message change will be on the time checking in opens.

And if your situation is not as straight forward, it might be a different case, you may not be able to check-in online at all.

KLM, if you read this, maybe you can add that one more word to the line, the word 'yet'.

Comment: "30 hours" depends on destination/airline; for USA it is 24 hours. See https://www.klm.com/travel/us_en/prepare_for_travel/checkin_options/internet_checkin/index.htm#p2

Comment: The word *nog* ("yet") would be a very good addition to that message.

Comment: It would have been, it would have saved me some worrying.

Comment: I asked KLM online about this and this is what they had to say:

_"Thanks for the suggestion, Burhan. However, some flights get's operated by different airlines. Therefore, you will be able to check-in at the airport."_ - which makes sense, although I don't think it applied in your case.